# Washing machine won't turn on - loose connector on PCB - how and where do I reattach it?

Tags: electrical, washing-machine, connectors, circuit

My washing machine is completely unresponsive when plugged in to a working outlet. I opened up the machine to take a look and found that this connector had come loose. It seemed to me that the 'mouth' of the connector probably attached to the row of 8 pins visible in the top left corner of picture 3 below. I tried pushing it into place but it was still a little loose, so I held it on whilst plugging in the machine to test. No luck, having tried both sides up.

Could anyone a little more familiar with PCBs advise me? Am I attaching the connector all wrong, or is there perhaps something missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Connector][image: Connector][image: Board][image: Board]

Comment: You could be right about the former location, but it would take some fine soldering skills to reattach it. Those appear to be surface-mount contacts (as opposed to through-mount). It might make sense to replace the board.

Comment: That looks like an Edge Connector. It seems to me as though it would slide onto the edge of the PCB at the *Bottom-Right* corner of your pic 3 (or somewhere similar with those "finger" contacts).

Comment: A closer look at that connector shows a keyway between pins 3 & 4, and the left end is closed - so it looks like it won't fit that particular position on that PCB. Look for similar features on the edge of that PCB or others. You'd need to find one with a slot cut out, then 3 'fingers' then another slot (for the keyway), then another 5 fingers.

Comment: We seem to have come to the same conclusions at the same time (you commented while I was writing my answer, so I had not seen your comments until after I was done writing.) By the way, "holding on while plugging in the machine to test" is a VERY dangerous game to play with mains-powered equipment. Please don't do that again, Clare.

Comment: What's the blue thing on the bottom of your first 2 pictures? It looks like it may be an electrical plug receptacle of some sort.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are trying the wrong location entirely.

That appears to be an edge connector [ it clips over the edge of a PCB ], and **at first** *I thought the spot where it goes is on the lower right of the 3rd picture and the lower left of the last picture.* But I don't think that is correct, looking closer.

It only goes on one way - the slot cut between the connector pads matches a divider between pins - but the position of the slot [7 pins one side, 1 pin on the other, while the plug has 3 pins on one side, 5 on the other] does not add up, and the closed end of the plug (up in your second picture) requires either another slot or a set of pads at the edge of the board it clips to.

[image]
[image]

So, you're looking for a **different** 8-pin edge connector on the PCB, but it'll have a divider between pins 3 and 4.

Comment: I was writing my own answer when you beat me to it; hope you don't mind my adding my stuff to yours.

Comment: What the heck, I'll just community-wiki the thing. I don't need the "points" ;-)